# TYPO3 v7.6 - How to render a tt_content on backend (Page Module)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm working on a TYPO3 v7.6 project and have created a Content Element with a flexform which contains a **group** type field allowing other **tt_content**. Here's the config for the field:

```
<config type="array">
    <type>group</type>
    <internal_type>db</internal_type>
    <allowed>tt_content</allowed>
    <size>5</size>
    <maxitems>200</maxitems>
    <minitems>0</minitems>
    <multiple>1</multiple>
    <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
</config>
```

The flexform works fine and I'm able to add content when editing it. However, what I need is to allow the user to move (drag and drop) content on the same page to inside that field, like what is possible when using TemplaVoila in previous versions.

I've created a hook for **tt_content_drawItem** which implements the interface *PageLayoutViewDrawItemHookInterface* and I was able to change the *preProcess* function for my plugin, but I have no idea on how to create a dropzone area with a "Create new content element" that allows tt_content to be moved into it.

Looks like the original TYPO3's *DragDrop.js* file that handle this is unable to move into content elements, but only into pages. Is this right?

Is there anyway of achieving this, or any extension that allows this functionality?

## EDIT

After some days of research and trying some extensions, I could find a solution which is suitable for my needs. I'm using the extension **fluidcontent** to create a content element with the following fluid template:

```
{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="Configuration">    
        <flux:grid>
                <flux:grid.row >
                    <flux:grid.column name="content" label="Content"/>
                </flux:grid.row>
            </flux:grid>
    </flux:form>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Preview">  
</f:section>

<f:section name="Main">
        <flux:content.render area="content" /> 
</f:section>
```

However, for my flexform fields which contains content areas I'm still not able to drag and drop or even visualize the content on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The extension Gridelements allows you to create content elements inside other content elements (much like TemplaVoilà did). I haven't tried if it allows you to drag content elements inside others, but I wouldn't be surprised if it covered that too.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do now is to put `<flux:widget.grid />` into the Preview section.

This is the code for my 2column content element (That is visible in the backend including drag&drop):

```
{namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}

    <f:layout name="Content" />

    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="2column" label="2 Columns" options="{icon: 'Icons/Content/Example.gif', group: 'MyGroup'}">
        </flux:form>
        <flux:grid>
            <flux:grid.row>
                <flux:grid.column colPos="0" label="Column 1" style="width: 50%" name="column1" />
                <flux:grid.column colPos="1" label="Column 2" style="width: 50%" name="column2" />
            </flux:grid.row>
        </flux:grid>
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Preview">
        <flux:widget.grid />
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Main">
        <div class="twocolumn1">
            <flux:content.render area="column1" />
        </div>
        <div class="twocolumn2">
            <flux:content.render area="column2" />  
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </f:section>
```